# Can we use ULN2003A to power up another module

Tags: uln2003

I have one requirement wherein, I need to power up one of the modules occasionally. I do not have relay in my controller board, but I have ULN2003A in my board. The module consumes around 400mA. So can I use ULN2003A to drive this external module? In case I can drive, how the connection will be? In case of relays, we give power to one side of the relay and the other side is connected to the collector of ULN.

Comment: that depends on what the other module is; no general answer is possible.

Comment: Let me say it is DFPlayer mini MP3 module.

Comment: And what are it’s power requirements and what power do you have available?

Comment: UNL2003A can only sink current, so you have to use it to make/break the Gnd connection of the module if you plan to use it as a power switch. And then depending on the current flow, that Gnd may be 1-2-3 volts above the power supply Gnd, which could cause issues with control signals going to the module.

Comment: You are better off finding a logic level gate P-channel MOSFET (one that will turn fully on with a low Rds when the gate is pulled low) that you can use to switch the power line of the module. Be sure to bring any control signals low before removing power so the control lines do not become phantom power lines to the module.

Comment: @CrossRoads, I think your answer is sensible.I better not use ULN, instead try to grab external relay module.

Comment: Relay module will work too.

Comment: Q1: What is supply voltage available for MP3? Q2: What minimum voltage will it work on? | ULN2003 is a low side switc and drops/loses about 1V. | Module floats high when off - if eg output leads are grounded this may turn module on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ULN2003A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf) is a 7 channel low-side driver that is rated for 500mA per channel, but drops ~1V at 400mA.

If your module will work with ~1V less than your supply voltage *and* its ground pin being raised by 1V isn't a problem then it may work (though the ~0.4 W power loss in the ULN2003A could make it very hot).

However if another device has to communicate with the module then the raised ground potential probably *will* be a problem, so it would be better to use the ULN2003A to switch a high-side power transistor, like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCJvVh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The high-side switching device can either be a PNP bipolar transistor (as shown here) or a P-channel MOSFET designed for 'logic level' Gate drive (eg. [IRLML5203](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlml5203pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566868da261d)). Either type should be rated for several Amps to ensure low voltage drop at 400mA.